# Moving elements on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Does anyone know why these two rectangles are not moving?

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/R5wx8/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    c = canvas.getContext('2d');

function move() {

    var x = 10,
        y = 15;

    c.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5),
    c.fillRect(y, x, 25, 55);
    x++;
    y++;
}

setInterval(move, 300);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring x and y each time the move method runs to be 10 and 15 again. Put the declarations of x and y outside of the method to get the rectangle to move.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
c = canvas.getContext('2d');


var x = 10;
var y = 15;

function move() {
    c.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5),
    c.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
    x++;
    y++;
}

setInterval(move, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it was a simple one. Just declare `x,y` outside the `move` function:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
c = canvas.getContext('2d'),
x = 10, y = 15;
```

See updated <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5wx8/1/)</kbd>